# php mvc fetch data in Database display dropdown

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dropdown

How should I add my model into my controller to display the values in drop down ? 
The error I get: *Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*
I didn't use any framework. Just native php. I am new in MVC and PHP please help!

My Controller:

```
<?php 
  class Index extends Controller {
    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }
    function index(){
      $landArray = $this->model->fetchData();
      $this->view->render('index/index');
      var_dump($landArray); // display all row in database
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Index_Model extends Model {
 function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }
 function fetchData(){
    $selectIsland = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT island_id, island 
                               from island" );
    $selectIsland->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $selectIsland->execute();
    $islandResult = $selectIsland->fetchAll();
    return $islandResult;

 }
}
```

View:

```
<select>
    <option value="">--- Select Island---</option>
      <?php
            foreach($islandResult as $row){
              echo '<option value="'.$row['island_id'].'">'.$row['island'].'</option>';
            endforeach
       }?>
</select>
```

This is my library View and render method.

```
<?php
class View {
 function __construct(){
  }
public function render($name, $noInclude = false, $landArray){
 if($noInclude == true){
   require 'views/'.$name.'.php';
  }else{
  require 'views/header.php';
  require 'views/'.$name.'.php';
  require 'views/foother.php';
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: are you using any framework?? or following mvc using raw php?

Comment: Hello I forgot to include in my question, I didn't use any framework just only PHP sorry I am new in PHP and MVC approach.

Comment: how does your `$this->view->render()` work?? did you implement it?

Comment: I can't see you passing any results to the view neither doing anything with the model. So you might pass null to the view

Comment: @AsifRahaman Yes it works it display the drop down but didn't fetch data in database.

Comment: okk...then see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never called `fetchData()` method of your model. In MVC controller controls everything. in your controller you have to call methods from model. then pass those to your view file.

```
<?php 
  class Index extends Controller {
    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }
    function index(){
      $landArray = $this->model->fetchData();
      $this->view->render('index/index', false, array('islandResult' => $landArray)); // as we are sending param to view and render accept that as 3rd param so we need to specify the 2nd param too!
    }
} 
Model:

<?php
class Index_Model extends Model {
 function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }
 function fetchData(){
    $selectIsland = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT island_id, island 
                               from island" );
    $selectIsland->execute();
    $islandResult = $selectIsland->fetchAll();
    return $islandResult;  //if you need something to pass to view from db first you have to pass it to controller from model
 }
}
View:

<select>
    <option value="">--- Select Island---</option>
      <?php
            foreach($islandResult as $row){
              echo '<option value="'.$row['island_id'].'">'.$row['island'].'</option>';
            }
       ?>
</select>

View/Render Library Method:

    class View {
         function __construct(){
         }
         public function render($name, $noInclude = false, $arrayParam = array()){ //look closely...here i've made 3rd parameter as default argument so that your other codes which don't need to send param to view works smoothly.
             if(count($arrayParam) > 0){
                 extract($arrayParam);
             }
             if($noInclude == true){
                 require 'views/'.$name.'.php';
             }else{
                 require 'views/header.php';
                 require 'views/'.$name.'.php';
                 require 'views/foother.php';
             }
         }
     }
```

Now you'll be able to use parameters in view which you are sending from controller. whatever you pass as array key in controller can be used as variable in view now.

N.B: check my comments from code.

Comment: just writing methods inside model doesn't mean they will call themselves. You've call them from your controller whenever you need. And if you need to pass something to your view then you need to pass as 2nd argument using `render()`. I guess your `render()` method also take 2nd parameter. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The error I get is : Invalid Argument supplied for foreach(). Actually I add the endforeach  I forgot to add it. But it is error again

Comment: Can you give an example of MVC approach in native php that fetch data in database then displays in drop down.

Comment: did you follow my answer?? previously i missed return statement in model which i've added later. Please check the updated answer again and let me know if it works.

Comment: The error was: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: try debugging... before `foreach($islandResult as $row){` this line add `var_dump($islandResult)` and see what `$islandResult` variable contains.. did you pass this variable from controller??

Comment: I landed it into my controller and it is NULL

Comment: But when I var_dump($landArray) definitely it displays all the row values in the database. The only problem is that this values cannot pass into my views. In the view part the error is Invalid Argument supplied foreach()

Comment: @Royce can you show me your updated code now?? and does your render method any 2nd parameter other than the view script name???

Comment: @Royce okk...see there's a little difference between mine and your solution. I've passed `$landArray` to view as parameter of `render()` method assuming it takes 2nd parameter. but you didn't. If you don't send `$landArray` as parameter then it wont be available in view.

Comment: check out my updated code I include the render method which I set as my library. I add the $lanArray as a parameter and it is error.

Comment: @Royce you've clearly missed some things. First of all you just updated your render() method but didn't update your other part of code as necessary. Anyway I've modified my answer again based on your updated code. Let me know if that helps.